# Special Character in completion type of elastic search

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I am a new user of elastic search, I have a mapping :-

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/vee_trade -d '
{
 "mappings": {
  "sDocument" : {
   "properties" : {
    "id" : { "type" : "long" },
    "docId" : { "type" : "string" },
    "documentType" : { "type" : "string" },
    "rating"  : { "type" : "float" },
    "suggestion" : { "type" :     "completion"}
    }
   }
  }
}
```

and one sample data is :-

```
 _index: "test"
 _type: "sDocument"
 _id: "CATEGORY7"
 _score: 1
 _source{}
 docId: "CATEGORY7"
 documentType: "CATEGORY"
 id: 7
 suggestion[]
 "Kids's wear"
 rating: null
```

Basically my aim is to enable auto-suggestion, which works for query but in auto-suggestion entries I only get terms and score values whereas I also want other field values,
so again I fire match query on suggestion field with the resultant auto-suggested terms

```
{
  "query" : {
   "match" : {
    "suggestion" : "Men's"  
    }
   }
}
```

but I don't get data as elastic removes special characters from terms looks like (not sure how its storing and indexing it) so please tell me

either  how to retrieve other field values along with search term in auto suggest ???  or how to make match query working ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: long answer. It's a little hard to tell exactly what the problem is from what you posted, so I'm giving you several options for things to explore that might help solve your problem.*

There are a few different ways you can go about what you are trying to do. I've written about two different autocomplete methods on the [Qbox blog](http://blog.qbox.io/), one post about using [completion suggest](http://blog.qbox.io/quick-and-dirty-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-completion-suggest) and one about using a more sophisticated setup involving [ngrams and multiple fields](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams).

I find the completion suggester to be a little clunky in practice (since you have to tell it explicitly what to respond to), so I tend to rely more on a custom analysis framework. One way you can experiment with analyzers is to set up multiple [sub-fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) (used to be called multi-fields) for a property. So I'll show a few examples below.

I'm going to set up a field with a couple of sub-fields that analyze the text in different ways, then just use a `match` query on each to show how it behaves.

Take a look at this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "standard",
               "search_analyzer": "standard",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "ngram": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                     "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

There's a lot going on here, and I encourage you to read up on [analysis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-analysis.html) and [ngrams](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer). Also, I took part of the code from my [partial-word autocomplete post](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams), so you might find it helpful to read through that for a more thorough explanation.

Basically, though, I have a single field, `"text_field"`, that is analyzed using the [`"standard"` analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-analyzer.html), both for indexing (i.e., the terms generated for a given document and field when creating the inverted index), and for searching (the way the search phrase is broken into terms to match against the terms in the inverted index). Then I have two different sub-fields on that field. One is not analyzed at all, so the only terms we can match against will be the raw text of the document field. The second sub-field is analyzed using the `"nGram_analyzer"` for indexing, and the `"whitespace_analyzer"` for searching, both of which are defined in the index's `"settings"`.

So now if we index a couple of documents:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "text_field": "Kid's wear"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
    "text_field": "Men's wear"
}
```

we can search against them in various ways.

Querying against `"text_field.raw"` will require the exact, full text to get a match:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text_field.raw": "Men's wear"
      }
   }
}
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Men's wear"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

A standard `"match"` query against `"text_field"` works as expected, since the term `"Men's"` will be tokenized into `"men"` both on indexing and on searching:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text_field": "Men's"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.625,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.625,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Men's wear"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

but if we add a second term we get results that might not be what we want:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text_field": "Men's wear"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.72711754,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.72711754,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Men's wear"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.09494676,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Kid's wear"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This happens because of the way terms are generated, and because the default operator for the match query is `"or"`. We can limit the results by specifying the [operator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-multi-word.html#match-improving-precision) the match query uses to be `"and"`:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text_field": {
             "query":  "Men's wear",
             "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.72711754,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.72711754,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Men's wear"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

We can use the `"text_field.ngram"` field to match on partial words (including symbols and punctuation, since that's specified in the definition of `"nGram_filter"` in our index settings):

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text_field.ngram": {
             "query":  "men's we",
             "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.72711754,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.72711754,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "Men's wear"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas about how to proceed.